# Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, weekday

I have an excel sheet with Columns having the dates of a month. The entire column needs to be colored based on whether the date in the header cell is a weekday or weekend, I tried using the Weekday formula, but unable to get the work done. 
Could anyone please guide me on this?

Image below shows the requirement.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you're using a VB macro to achieve this, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use conditional formatting like this:

[image]

Basically, highlight the columns, from the Home tab, select 'Conditional Formatting' > 'New Rule' > 'Use a formula ...', use `=WEEKDAY(A$1,2)>5` (A is the cell of the lighter cell from the highlighted range, $1 is the header row, the $ sign ensures that the condition always checks the 1st row), then select the formatting of your choice.

Repeat similar steps for weekdays, except this time the formula will be `=WEEKDAY(A$1,2)<6` (or equivalent `=WEEKDAY(A$1,2)<=5`, etc) and the format will be different.

Comment: Yea, now that I think about it, it would indeed be more convenient. Oh well, for the sake of flexibility and cover the main purpose of the problem, I'll keep the answer as is.